# Can you transfer files off the iPad with Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, file-transfer, ipad

Can you transfer files off the iPad with Bluetooth? Or do you have to buy a 3rd party add-on?

From Google, it seems like you needed a 3rd party app to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Not by default, no.

Take a look at Apple's [Supported Bluetooth Profiles for iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647), different devices support different profiles; however, general file transfer is not one of them.

[image]

> Additional Information Here are some common uses for each of the
>   Bluetooth profiles listed above.
>
> **Hands-Free Profile (HFP 1.6)** Hands-Free Profile allows Bluetooth
>   headsets and car hands-free kits to communicate with mobile phones.
>
> **Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP)** Phone Book Access Profile allows the
>   exchange of Phone Book Objects between iPhone and other Bluetooth
>   devices.
>
> It is often used between a car kit and a mobile phone to:
>
> Allow the car kit to display the name of the incoming caller Allow the
>   car kit to sync the phone book so the user can initiate a call from
>   the car display Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP) Advanced
>   Audio Distribution Profile allows high quality audio (stereo or mono)
>   to be streamed from one device to another over a Bluetooth connection.
>   This is commonly used to play music wirelessly from iOS to a wireless
>   headset or a compatible car audio system.
>
> **Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP 1.4)** Audio/Video Remote
>   Control Profile allows remote control of playback functions on the iOS
>   device from compatible devices (commonly Bluetooth devices that use
>   the A2DP profile). The latest version of iOS supports the following
>   commands: pause, play, stop, next track, previous track, and browsing.
>
> **Personal Area Network Profile (PAN)** Personal Area Network Profile
>   provides network connectivity over Bluetooth. With iOS this is common
>   with multiplayer games and Personal Hotspot on iPhone. See this
>   article for additional information.
>
> iPod touch and iPad with iOS 4.3 or later support Internet tethering
>   from an iPhone with iOS 4.2.6 or later, through PAN.
>
> **Human Interface Device Profile (HID)** Human Interface Device Profile
>   allows communication between iOS and Bluetooth keyboards.
>
> **Message Access Profile (MAP)** Message Access Profile allows exchange of
>   messages between devices. It is mostly used for automotive hands-free
>   use.
>
> Note: iOS requires that the remote Bluetooth device support an
>   encrypted connection. When establishing a pairing record between your
>   iOS device and a Bluetooth device, you are also setting up encryption
>   between the two devices.

Comment: Whoever voted this down, just as the other, please explain why. Seeing as it addresses the question and cites the sources. If you provide feedback, the questions can be improved (system wide, not just these cases).

Answer (score 2):

In order to transfer files with Bluetooth, you will probably need to download an app. There are many out there.

Another (in my opinion, better) method of transferring files, is wireless. Download the Documents 2 app from the app store. It allows you to transfer files via your wifi connection. I happen to use it all the time and it works great.

**Note: I am not advertising for anyone. Any app that does this will work. I happen to use this app and it works remarkably.**

Hope that this answer helped.